# Android 5 update randomly aborted on my Nexus 4

Tags: updates, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, ota-update

I have a Nexus 4 phone. It's not rooted nor customized with any mod.

Today I (finally) received the update to Android 5.0.1, which I downloaded. After the download, I clicked on the **Restart and install** button (my phone's in French so translation might not be exact). The countdown before restarting the phone then began but after a few seconds I have been redirected to a screen telling me my system was up to date.

I tried to search for updates but nothing showed up and now I have no idea where the heck the update went. My phone still displays Android version 4.4.4 and is visibly still running Android 4.4.4.

What am I supposed to do now?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Nexus Root Toolkit to sideload the [OTA updates](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=33631631&postcount=1).  Links:

- [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/)
- [Nexus 4 OTA (LRX21T from KTU84P)](http://r1---sn-mv-nh4e.c.android.clients.google.com/packages/data/ota/google_mako/1c6f10c34ed54fb29844906b2f041c900ba23a6b.signed-occam-LRX21T-from-KTU84P.1c6f10c3.zip?cms_redirect=yes&expire=1418360280&ip=67.108.13.66&ipbits=0&mm=31&ms=au&mt=1418345809&mv=m&sparams=expire,ip,ipbits,mm,ms,mv&signature=1AEA3B9C3ACF98565D8E8D5881EDF6A01CF9376F.31956ADCAE07498200AFDBC172C8F825313258BF&key=cms1)
- [Nexus 4 OTA (LRX22C from LRX21T)](http://r1---sn-mv-nh4e.c.android.clients.google.com/packages/data/ota/google_mako/e93b20be8653fe5fd9951f3d38c169d5710ea986.signed-occam-LRX22C-from-LRX21T.e93b20be.zip?cms_redirect=yes&expire=1418348771&ip=67.108.13.66&ipbits=0&mm=31&ms=au&mt=1418334325&mv=m&sparams=expire,ip,ipbits,mm,ms,mv&signature=4137F963CB500510CA56C4F0830BEBEA5741C5E6.17FE1D2817C714127FE217DDE4C9FDD7F8EF4E82&key=cms1)

Hit Launch in the Advanced Utilities pane, then hit the Sideload Update button, and point to the OTA zip from above.  Follow the instructions.  No typing involved.

I don't know of a single LRX22C from KTU84P OTA.